# No theoretical frequency should be less than 5

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, inference, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

Why does the theoretical frequency in chi-square distribution should not be less than 5? What's the concept behind pooling the preceding and succeeding frequency to make pooled frequency more than 5?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/35657/35989, it's just a rule of thumb.

Comment: I am confident you can find a very great many explanations by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chi+squared+5).  The rule of 5 applies only for situations with small numbers of degrees of freedom -- it can be considerably relaxed for larger numbers.