# Apparent fallacy in Fisher-Irwin test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, independence, fishers-exact-test

For a hypothesis $H_0\equiv p_1=p_2$ (for two Bernoulli distributions), we take a measurement and find that $X_1=i,X_2=j$, and we denote $k=i+j$

Now, to test $H_0$, the Fisher-Irwin test tells us to compute $$P_{H_0}(X_1=i|X_1+X_2=k)=\frac{\tbinom{n_1}{i}\tbinom{n_2}{k-i}}{\tbinom{n_1+n_2}{k}}$$

As I understand this, this probability is *supposed* to be "the probability that we would get the measured data $i,k$ in a measurement assuming that $H_0$ is true". We then compare this probability with the significance level, as in any other hypothesis testing exercise -- we always calculate the probability that we would obtain the measured dataset, and then compare with the significance level.

However, the given expression is *not* the probability that we would get the data $i,k$ in a measurement assuming that $H_0$ is true". That probability is $$P_{H_0}(X_1=i \:\cap X_1+X_2=k )=P_{H_0}(X_1=i|X_1+X_2=k)\times P_{H_0}(X_1+X_2=k)$$

The probability distribution suggested by the Fisher-Irwin test seems to miss out the fact that there are two independent variables and not one ($X_1$ and $X=X_1+X_2$). The expression gives me the impression that it is presupposing $X=k$  and then going on to deal with the probability for $X_1$.

Why do we use $P_{H_0}(X_1=i|X_1+X_2=k)$ in the Fisher-Irwin test and not $P_{H_0}(X_1=i \:\cup X_1+X_2=k)$? The explanation<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXhCk.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlVIl.png)</sup> given in Sheldon Ross' book isn't quite convincing.

Comment: "*we always calculate the probability that we would obtain the measured dataset*" -- not so. See wikipedia's definition of what a [p-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) is. The test in question simply *conditions* on the margins. Not everyone agrees that conditioning is always appropriate in all the situations the test is used for -- that's a debate that's been running for many decades.

Comment: Some possible further clarification: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14227/805