# Does N-1 correction for Pearson's Chi-Square apply to r x c tables generally?

Tags: chi-squared-test, count-data, contingency-tables, type-i-and-ii-errors, tables

Campbell (2007) recommended what he called the "N-1" correction for chi-square tests performed on *two-by-two* contingency tables. He described the correction as:

> "the K. Pearson chi-squared test but with N replaced by N − 1".

The purpose of the correction is to reduce the rate of Type I errors, for contingency tables where the minimum expected frequency is at least 1. Otherwise, he recommended using the Fisher-Irwin test. Campbell's recommendation has been encouraged by posters to CrossValidated [(example)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14226/given-the-power-of-computers-these-days-is-there-ever-a-reason-to-do-a-chi-squa?lq=1).

My question is whether the 'N-1' correction should be used for  *r* x *c* tables generally? For example, would one apply it to a chi-square test for a three-by-five table? Or is it's use limited to two-by-two tables?

Campbell, Ian. 2007.  Chi-squared and Fisher-Irwin tests of two-by-two tables with small sample recommendations. *Statistics in Medicine* **26**: 3661-3675.

Comment: The author has his preprint [here](http://www.iancampbell.co.uk/twobytwo/files/campbell_twobytwo_preprint.pdf)

Comment: it may also be worth people looking at the comment by Antonio Martín Andrés the following year (there's a link on the [pubmed page](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17315184) for the Campbell paper), since it raises a number of issues. One can always use simulation from the relevant model for one's situation instead.

Comment: There's also [this](http://www.iancampbell.co.uk/twobytwo/results.htm) followup by Campbell. \[See also [this](http://www.iancampbell.co.uk/twobytwo/n-1_theory.htm) and perhaps [this](http://www.iancampbell.co.uk/twobytwo/sawtooth_appearance.htm).\]

Comment: Having read the paper (&some of the other material), and A. Martín Andrés' comment, my guess is that - if you're looking for a basis akin to that used by Campbell, unless there's further research I haven't seen, it's probably an open question (unless someone wants to undertake a much larger study than Campbell did just to answer the question). The justification that the $N-1$ adjustment corresponds to an unbiased estimate of the variance of the proportion should still carry over to larger tables, but there's no clear reason to expect the type I error rate will also correspond in rxc tables.