# How to prove significantly high or low values?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, p-value

I have the counts of genes in particular pathways from three organisms. How to statistically prove that few counts are significantly high or low as compared to another organism.

My data looks like this :
[image]

Is it possible to calulate p value for particular count compared between organisms.
e.g. how to check in row 3 whether value, 5 (Org3) is significantly different (lower) from 25 and 21  (i.e. from org1 and org2) or not?
Please suggest which test is suitable and how to go about.

**UPDATED ONE POSSIBLE ANSWER MYSELF**.

Comment: Did you check out http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14226/given-the-power-of-computers-these-days-is-there-ever-a-reason-to-do-a-chi-squa?

Answer (score 1):

I came across **Kruskal-Wallis Rank Sum Test** in R.
[This page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kruskal.test.html) explains the usage.

Try this demo example in R console:

```
## Hollander & Wolfe (1973), 116.
## Mucociliary efficiency from the rate of removal of dust in normal
##  subjects, subjects with obstructive airway disease, and subjects
##  with asbestosis.
x <- c(2.9, 3.0, 2.5, 2.6, 3.2) # normal subjects
y <- c(3.8, 2.7, 4.0, 2.4)      # with obstructive airway disease
z <- c(2.8, 3.4, 3.7, 2.2, 2.0) # with asbestosis
kruskal.test(list(x, y, z))
## Equivalently,
x <- c(x, y, z)
g <- factor(rep(1:3, c(5, 4, 5)),
            labels = c("Normal subjects",
                       "Subjects with obstructive airway disease",
                       "Subjects with asbestosis"))
kruskal.test(x, g)

## Formula interface.
require(graphics)
boxplot(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality)
kruskal.test(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality)
```