# How to modify Fisher's exact test if sample size if larger than 20?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, python, inference, hypergeometric-distribution

I have a 2x2 contingency table with the following values: $$A = 20, B = 10, C = 200, D = 300$$
As you can see, the sample size is much larger than $20$, the recommended sample size if one were to use the Fisher's exact test. I read this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14226/given-the-power-of-computers-these-days-is-there-ever-a-reason-to-do-a-chi-squa/14230#14230) that suggested to do a simple $\frac{N-1}{N}$. However, I don't quite understand why or how to do this.

**Hence, is there a more general way(for large sample sizes) to compute this hyper geometric distribution instead of just the fisher test?**

I considered a chi-squared test, but I'm in need of something more conservative.

Lastly, as a side note, I saw this [docs page for fisher test by python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html). However, I'm not able to find much documentation on whether this will work well for large sample sizes. Not to mention, it has a note saying it uses conditional maximum likelihood where as `R` uses unconditional. Some clues on which version is better and what their respective mathematical equations would look like would also be nice to know.

Comment: Why do you think chi-squared test is too liberal? All expected values seem to be large enough to me? Fisher's exact test is still valid, but it becomes numerically harder for such a large sample sizes.

Comment: If you have large N and large expected frequencies in all cells (as you do here) then why do you want Fisher's exact test at all?

Comment: Running your example on my machine using R and the fisher.test command  is virtually instantaneous.

Comment: I have to write software that reads data and does statistical analysis using python, hence, my question regarding the conditional/unconditional maximum likelihood. Between the answers provided by R and Python, what should I use for different situations? @mdewey

Comment: From my understanding, the fisher exact test is more accurate. However, I guess if my data is so large, than chi-square might offer accurate values anyway... hmm. @PeterFlom

Comment: Actually, after making the post, I researched around and I'm actually more convinced that I should be using a chi-square test. Why would a fisher's exact test still be valid if more than 80% of the expected values are greater than 5? Or is that not a hard set rule?

Comment: My professor suggested to me to use a hypergeometric test for our data. However, I wasn't sure how to amend that test for a 2x2 contigency table other than using a Fisher exact test, especially since it uses hypergeometric distribution. But i'm open to new suggestions, given the right reasoning so I can convince my professor which test to use over the one he suggested. @PeterFlom

Comment: There is no reason NOT to use Fisher's exact test, except computation time. No adjustment should be needed.

Comment: So what about the rule regarding no more than 80% of expected values being greater than 5? @PeterFlom

Comment: That is a reason TO use it, not a reason NOT to do so. Once all the expected frequencies are large, you don't HAVE to use Fisher's, but you still can.

Comment: @Christian The 'rule' you're talking about is a rough rule of thumb relating to when the asymptotic chi-squared approximation to the null distribution of the chi-squared test statistic may be poor (the rule says not to use the ordinary chi-square when too many of the expected values are below 5). In that case sometimes people choose the Fisher Exact test, but higher expected counts are not an inherent reason to avoid Fisher's Exact test. There's nothing to "modify"; the test does the same thing either way.

Comment: If you feel like that mostly answers your question I guess I could post it as an answer. (We have a lot of questions relating to this test which you should probably also check out; at least some of these briefly mention conditional vs unconditional calculations). Note that for the 2x2 case the Fisher test is based on the ordinary hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: Yes, the collective information from these comments definitely helps and serves as a great source of clarification! Please post as an answer so I can accept!