# Is there alternative to Fisher's Exact Test for 6X2 contingency table with the hypothesis of "less than"?

Tags: r, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I have a table of contingency which is 6X2 and in my case, it is not an option to "convert" it in a 2X2 table. Also, I need to be able to use the hypothesis of "less than" and "greater than" (I mean, I cannot be restricted to the "two sided"). The Fisher test in R (fisher.test) allows for all three hypothesis only when the table of contingency is 2X2. Do you know of any other test that I can apply here?

Comment: What would *less than* or *greater than* mean here in a multidimensional sense? Combined, are they equivalent to *different*?

Comment: A reason why Fisher's exact rarely goes beyond 2x2 is that the calculations become *very* cumbersome (already in the standard case there's a lot of factorials in there). The $\chi^2$ test with appropriate correction is just outright better as long as your expected cell frequencies exceed 1 - see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14230/353280) for more discussion.

Comment: And since Fisher’s “exact” test is not very accurate, why ever use it?  This has been discussed at length on this site.  Another issue: what makes up the 6 categories?  Can they be ordered?

Comment: @Pbulls It's easy to obtain p-values to any desired level of accuracy for a specific set of margins by simulation; it's not really necessary to worry about lots of factorials. Very large tables become unwieldy  but 6x2 is not problematic.